# Service 'Sql Server VSS writer' (SQLWriter) failed to start when installing LocalDB

Tags: sql-server, localdb

I am on machine with .NET 4.5.2 framework where I am trying to install SQLLocalDB 2019 and launching with administrator, but while installing it's prompting error on service start. Could someone suggest why?

[image: ald]

Comment: Related: [SQL Server VSS Writer refuses to start](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16160310/1364007)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Had the same issue and it turns out you need to install the Visual C++ Redistributable 2015 or newer.
https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/VC_redist.x64.exe

IMO the SQL Server installer should handle this for you, but it doesn't.

Comment: I encountered this problem during installation of the SQL Server 2019 express edition. The installation failure suggested me to install [Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable (x64)](https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/vc_redist.x64.exe). But, even after installing the 2017 redistributable the problem _persisted_. However, the redistributable provided by the link in this answer is titled "Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2019 Redistributable (x64)" actually **solved my problem**. The latter's version number is 14.28.29325 whereas that of the former (2017) is 14.16.27033.

Comment: This solved it for me as well when installing LocalDB 2022 on Windows Server 2022